# 'Kindly make sure to let's know'

Tags: orthography

I received an email from my team lead, which says:

> Kindly make sure to let's know the challenges you faced while working on the project.

It was the reply to my email which presented challenges. 
I think the above reply from my team lead doesn't sound correct (I may be incorrect).
I would like to rephrase it:

> Kindly make sure to let us know if you face any challenges.

Am I correct about the contraction here? And is the rest correct?

Comment: You are correct. Not sure the name of the rule or convention, but contractions in such cases are, if not discouraged outright, highly irregular.

Comment: In this case "let's" is a contraction for "lettuce".

Comment: @NigelJ What is wrong with ..."Let's go" ? Common expression and used by perfectly mature adults...

Comment: @Cascabel Let's agree on that.

Comment: Let’s fret over this no longer.

Comment: @HotLicks...and as you probably already know, it is a reference to a vegetable used in many churches every Sunday upon the invitation to  invoke the Spirit...

Comment: @Cascabel - Thought it was an invitation to hunt.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds racist, but is this a _rabbit_ thing? @HotLicks

Comment: @Cascabel - Lettuce prey, Brother!

Comment: This is one of those cases like how you cannot answer "Is it true?" with a contracted "It's" and nothing else to mean "It is", even though "It is" by itself and even "It’s true" are both ok.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question and improving its readability. I want you all to know that I have no doubt about contractions.

Comment: I also want to know, will there be the past tense of the word 'face' in my TL's reply?

Answer (score 3):

While "let's" is derived from contracting "let us", it is now a fixed term with a specific meaning. It would be slightly odd to write "let us" to mean "we should" (it's a bit overly formal), and it's very odd to write "let's" to mean "let us".

To be idiomatic, a contraction has be one that is standard, and being a standard contraction is a property of not only the words being contracted, but the meaning those words are being used in. So, for instance, if we use the word "will" in the sense of "last testament", it would not be idiomatic to say "Is the won't here?" to mean "Is the will not here?"

Comment: Sorry, but I provided a little formatting to improve readability...hope you don't mind.